# Bootstrap logo image on top of navbar mvc asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to put an image on top of the navigation bar and I'm not getting, follows the script

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">            
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried some examples and could not.

Comment: See this -http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/MMdrJ/2/

Comment: The Logo must appear on the navigation bar, in this instance appearing beside.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar has the tag `navbar-fixed-top`, you need to change it to `relative`.